# Python string format with variable precision using string-literals

Tags: python, string, variables, format

I would like to format a string `x` using string-literals (python 3.6+) obtaining the precision from a variable `n`.

```
def strtrunc(x, n):
    return(f'{x:.ng}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself while writing the question: Variables in string formatting can be nested as follows (seen in [Format string in python with variable formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498434/format-string-in-python-with-variable-formatting)), also works for string-literals:

```
def strtrunc(x, n):
    return(f'{x:.{n}g}')
strtrunc(x=12.34534, n=5)
Out[188]: '12.345'
```